# Как создать пустой строковый массив определенной длины в Kotlin?

Tags: массивы, kotlin

Как создать пустой строковый массив определенной длины в Kotlin?

Comment: так пустой или определенной длины?

Comment: пустой массив нужной длины как в java int[] myArray = new int[10]

Comment: в этом случае массив не пустой, у него элементы будут значениями по умолчанию. В котлине это равносильно получению массиву с null для строк: [`val stringsOrNulls = arrayOfNulls<String>(10)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44239940/2881286)

Comment: этот массив можно будет заполнить другими значениями?

Comment: да, конечно, просто записать нужно значение по нужному индексу

Comment: сделай ответ отмечу его решением

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вернуть массив строк заданного размера можно воспользоваться методом [arrayOfNulls](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of-nulls.html)

```
val arr = arrayOfNulls<String>(5)
```

В этом случае `arr` будет массивом с пятью элементами `null`.

Альтернативным решением может быть использованием конструктора с инициализатором

```
val arr = Array<String>(5) { "" };
```

В этом случае `arr` будет массивом с пятью элементами равными пустой строке.